# Transitioning Multi-Headed Projects from SVN to HG

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, project-organization

We are joining the modern world and transitioning from SVN to Mercurial for source control. Most of it is pretty straightforward -- just import the current trunk into HG and clone. One project is a bit fancier and I'm not seeing the correct way to do this.

The project in question is actually 4 separate web applications, 3 of which are effectively branches of a single common thread [called CORE]. From a SVN point of view, it looks like:

```
(root)
--CORE
--PROJECT-A
----YEAR-1
----YEAR-2
--PROJECT-B
```

Workflow-wise, changes to the core can come from either PROJECT-A or PROJECT-B and are merged back into CORE.

The question I have is "how should I put this together in HG and still be able to merge changes into the CORE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a multistage conversion process, where each of those projects becomes a named branch.

Then, I would use the convert extension to munge out your common code into a common subrepo; each of your projects would get its own 'upper' repo.

The common subrepo would have a branch for each project, and occasional merges to each other.

Comment: Interesting. Does it change things a bit if there are some slight variances in the "common code" here and there, especially during the development cycle?

Comment: Well, that's what the branches are for, you might have a PROJ1 branch and a PROJ2 branch in the dev cycle, then merge them together at the appropriate place.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be the right approach. Now, if hg convert was windows friendly . . .

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... perhaps Project-A and Project-B could be subrepos of CORE?

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository